# Power BI client opening tag not closing in Angular app

Tags: angular, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I'm trying to use a Microsoft component for embedding Power BI reports in an Angular application and so far the provided code is causing parsing errors. The following snippet from the GitHub instructions generates an error that the closing tag for "powerbi-report is not terminated". Is the syntax in the MicroSoft starting code sample incorrect is might this be another issue?

```
<powerbi-report
    [embedConfig] = {{
        type: "report",
        id: "<Report Id>",
        embedUrl: "<Embed Url>",
        accessToken: "<Access Token>",
        tokenType: models.TokenType.Embed,
        settings: {
            panes: {
                filters: {
                    expanded: false,
                    visible: false
                }
            },
            background: models.BackgroundType.Transparent,
        }
    }}

    [cssClassName] = { "reportClass" }

    [phasedEmbedding] = { false }

    [eventHandlers] = {
        new Map([
            ['loaded', () => console.log('Report loaded');],
            ['rendered', () => console.log('Report rendered');],
            ['error', (event) => console.log(event.detail);]
        ])
    }
>
</powerbi-report>
```

Answer (score 1):

Code You copied from github is from Readme file. The problem is with the passing props in Angular. You can find the correct code snippet from github repository Angular -> demo -> app folder.

```
<powerbi-report [embedConfig]="reportConfig" [cssClassName]="reportClass" [phasedEmbedding]="phasedEmbeddingFlag" [eventHandlers]="eventHandlersMap">
</powerbi-report>
```

References:

https://github.com/microsoft/powerbi-client-angular/blob/main/Angular/demo/src/app/app.component.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are unable to get your powerbi component to work you can always just do a Iframe like

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
          <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" [src]="dynamicPowerBiURL | safe"
              frameborder="0" allowFullScreen="true">
          </iframe>
 </div>
```

of course the dynamicPowerBiURL is just the variable that holds the url value that comes from your powerbi report.